# Overlay a view over other ListView rows

Tags: react-native

In my React Native app, I have a ListView component where a row is used to search for a person's name, is it possible to have the search results be shown in a list view which is over any subsequent rows?

Here is a mockup of that I am trying to achieve.

Underneath the *Full name* row there are other rows, so the result list needs to be overlaid. At the moment, when I try this, the list is cut off at the bottom edge of the *Full name* row.

[image]

I've tried to increase the height of the view of the first row, as well as increasing the *zIndex* of the result list view (and combinations thereof) trying to pop the it above the subsequent rows. The following shows the container view (in green) and the result list view (in orange).

[image]

I may just have to drop the ListView and build the sections and rows myself, for better control, and to get the above desired effect.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Just to make sure,Do you want it for iOS or react-native?
You want a cell where user will type full name and below the cells, all results are shown, right?

Comment: @elk_cloner React Native. I've changed the wording to reflect that.

Comment: Looks to me like you'll need to consider the content size of your scroll view and possibly listen to keyboard events to determine how high you want the full name cell to be when a user is typing. A lot of things to consider here and I'm sure there are a few ways to do this.

Comment: @sooper That was one thought, a compromised in a way, that when I need to show the result list, maybe I need to animate the row getting taller to accomodate the results.